# Whats the difference between a 'page', a 'panel', and a 'handler'?

Tags: panels, 7

I am porting a site over and looking through the code, and in a module there are folders for pages, handlers, and plugins/layouts (containing panels layouts) . The pages and handler folders contain .inc files. They are exports of pages and panels etc. However, what is the definitive difference between a handler, panel, and page?
Thanks

Comment: You mean what is the difference between them for the Panels (and Ctools) module? Otherwise you have to provide the codes of these files. Their names mean nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you navigate to admin/structure/panels. It gives a short description.

**Panel page**

Panel pages can be used as landing pages. They have a URL path, accept arguments and can have menu entries.

**Custom content**
Custom content panes are basic HTML you enter that can be reused in all of your panels.